# Need to split string(formula) with specified pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i need to split the following string into mentioned pattern

```
String str = "([myString1 - L]*[myString2 - L])/([myString3 - D]+[myString4 - N])";
```

and i want the output like following lines:

```
1. (
2. [myString1 - L]
3. *
4. [myString2 - L]
5. )
6. /
7. (
8. [myString3 - D]
9. +
10. [myString4 - N]
11. )
```

Comment: You know you need to use regex, because you tagged the question with it, so go ahead and try first...

Comment: @RGraham:  actually i have tried for it but not succeed yet.... because every time the string(formula) will change and we cannot stick to particular patter to split :(

Comment: That's cool, but what do you expect of us then? Some magic formula that would adapt automatically to new string formats?

Comment: This isn't a job for Regex, it's a job for a parser.

Comment: Why is it `4. [myString2 - L])`, `9. [myString4 - N]`, `10.)` and not `4. [myString2 - L])`,  `9. [myString4 - N])` or `4. [myString2 - L]`, `5. )`?

Comment: @RGraham: Well what `regex` have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [neoistheone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359745/need-to-split-stringformula-with-specified-pattern/19360027#comment28685090_19359745) that this looks like a job for a parser, but nonetheless you could use a regex like

```
var str = "([myString1 - L]*[myString2 - L])/([myString3 - D]+[myString4 - N])";
var result = Regex.Split(str, @"(\[[^]]+\]|[/\*\+\(\)])").Where(r => r != "").ToList();
```

which will give you the output you want (as long as your input stays that simple, e.g. no nested expressions in your input).

Answer (score 1):

Well matching on what you've specified you could try

```
new Regex(@"(?<=[(*/+)])(?=.)|(?<=.)(?=[(*/+)])").Split(str);
```

This will match

- either preceding char is `*`, `/`, `(`, `)` or `+` and the next character exists
- or next char is `*`, `/`, `(`, `)` or `+` and the preceding character exists

You need that preceding/next character exists check otherwise it will split at the beginning / end of your string.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like you're trying to parse an equation... (perhaps to then use with the [Shunting-yar algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) :)  So really, you want to break up the equation into 3 categories:

1. Operators (*,/,+,- ...)
2. Operands ([myString1 - D]
3. Parentheses

To use regular expressions, I would google it... there are many resources, but the cheat sheet I use is: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

It has most of the operations you're wanting.

Each category I described above should be it's own group. You would then want to `or` them together.

This gives us:

```
(<?operator>[\+\-\*\/])|(<?operand>\w\s\-\[LD])|(<?par>[\(\)])
```

This will return one match per part. So you would just want to keep cycling until you don't have any more matches.